# What doest "x HTTPS upgrades" mean in Brave browser?

Tags: https, brave

I have just discovered [Brave](https://brave.com/) browser and one of the features is called HTTPS upgrades. I tried to find out what it means, but could not find any relevant information:

[image: Brave new tab statistics]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about using a web application as it's defined on [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brave browser implemented directly this extension (or modification of it) **[HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere)** into itself, which basically tries to force sites to be loaded as HTTPS if it's possible (the reason is that many websites are poorly designed and even if they claim to support HTTPS, they are not (or not aware) due to wrong implementation of HTTPS protocol)

> HTTPS Everywhere is produced as a collaboration between The Tor Project and the Electronic Frontier Foundation. Many sites on the web offer some limited support for encryption over HTTPS, but make it difficult to use. For instance, they may default to unencrypted HTTP, or fill encrypted pages with links that go back to the unencrypted site. The HTTPS Everywhere extension fixes these problems by using clever technology to rewrite requests to these sites to HTTPS.

Comment: *(the reason is ... HTTPS protocol)* may have been the case, but anno 2019 that is exaggerating a little. Well, you're quoting *them* at the time of early development.